# Execute function when one of many checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onchange

I have some check boxes in a table as shown below:

```
    <table id="checkBoxTable" class="uk-margin-small-top uk-hidden checkBoxTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td><label id="1"><input name="1" type="checkbox"> 12am-1am</label</td>
            <td><label id="2"><input name="2" type="checkbox"> 1am-2am</label</td>
            <td><label id="3"><input name="3" type="checkbox"> 2am-3am</label></td>
            <td><label id="4"><input name="4" type="checkbox"> 3am-4am</labe</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to execute a function whenever any of the checkboxes are checked. I've been trying the following:

```
$('#checkBoxTable').change(function(){
        var price = 10 * originalPrice;
        $('#price').value = price + "";

    });
```

Comment: `if($('#checkBoxTable :checkbox:checked').length)`

Answer (score 0):

Target checkbox input[type="checkbox"]

```
$('#checkBoxTable input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var price = 10 * originalPrice;
    $('#price').value = price + "";
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are selecting `#checkBoxTable` which is `id` of the table. You should use `#checkBoxTable :checkbox` to select `checkbox` elements.

`$('#checkBoxTable :checkbox:checked'` will return `checked` input elements.

```js
var originalPrice = 100;
$('#checkBoxTable :checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($('#checkBoxTable :checkbox:checked').length) {
    var price = 10 * originalPrice;
    alert(price);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="checkBoxTable" class="uk-margin-small-top uk-hidden checkBoxTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label id="1">
        <input name="1" type="checkbox">12am-1am</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="2">
        <input name="2" type="checkbox">1am-2am</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="3">
        <input name="3" type="checkbox">2am-3am</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="4">
        <input name="4" type="checkbox">3am-4am</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/c3q310tq/)